# PermissionError: [WinError 32] O arquivo ja esta sendo usado por outro processo: 'D:\\Renomear\\PDF\\\\Teste.pdf'

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um programa em Python no windows para renomear um PDF de acordo com uma string que está dentro dele, porém na hora de renomear está retornando o seguinte erro:

PermissionError: [WinError 32] O arquivo ja esta sendo usado por outro processo: 'D:\Renomear\PDF\\Teste.pdf' -> 'D:\Renomear\PDF\\JOAO DA SILVA SANTOS  Teste.pdf'

```
import PyPDF2
import os

pdf = open ('D:\Renomear\PDF\Teste.pdf\\', 'rb')
reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf)
pagina = reader.getPage (0)
texto = pagina.extractText()
dividido = texto.split()[32:41] #separa as palavras 32 ate a 41
juntar = ' '.join(dividido)
string = juntar
newstring = ''.join([i for i in juntar if not i.isdigit()]) # remove os numeros da string restante

print(newstring)
    
folder = r'D:\Renomear\PDF\\'

for file_name in os.listdir(folder):
    old_name = folder + file_name
    new_name = folder + newstring + file_name 

    os.rename(old_name,new_name)
```

Comment: Embora tenha jeito mais elegante, acredito que logo abaixo da linha do `reader` você deva fechar o `pdf` com `pdf.close()`.

Comment: O PyPDF2 está obsoleto e não deve mais ser utilizado, veja o [histórico de desenvolvimento do PyPDF](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/meta/history.html). O módulo a ser utilizado segundo [o próprio autor do projeto](https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot/issues/339#issuecomment-1366979301) é o [pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/).

Answer (score -1):

Para quem não está a fim de ler nada:

**- só dá um pdf.close() antes de renomear o arquivo.**

Estava tendo um problema parecido agora a pouco, mas daí encontrei a solução:

dê um pdf.close() antes de você renomear o arquivo "teste.pdf".Você abriu o arquivo "teste.pdf", mas você não o fechou antes de o renomear, por isso o erro.A mensagem "o arquivo ja esta sendo usado por outro processo" provavelmente se refere ao seu editor de código que está com o seu arquivo pdf aberto, já que você não o fechou.

A abordagem que você usa para manipular arquivos funciona bem, mas se quiser uma dica: você pode utilizar a declaração with para manipular arquivos ao invés.Quais as vantagens do with?Aqui vai:

- **Fecha sozinho o arquivo e evita vazamento de recursos:** o with fecha o arquivo automaticamente, ou seja, você não precisa dar "arquivo.close()", o with faz isso automaticamente.Assim você não só não precisa fechar o arquivo manualmente, como você também evita que haja vajamento de recursos.
- **Deixa o código mais legível:** não só mais legível, como também mais elegante, vai por mim :).
- **Lida melhor com exceções:** o with consegue fazer a liberação de recursos mesmo nos casos em que ocorrem alguma exceção.Não te convenci muito?No método tradicional de manipulação de arquivos, você precisa tratar as exceções manualmente, enquanto que o with faz tudo isso pra você.
- **Funciona melhor em diferentes S.Os:** você com certeza vai querer que seu software funcione em multiplas plataformas, nesse caso, por que não usar o with visto que ele é compatível com vários S.Os?

Com certeza deve haver outras vantagens, mas só com as vantagens acima eu já devo ter te convencido sobre o quão "melhor" pode ser usar o with em relação o método mais tradicional.E você deve estar se perguntando: como usar essa maravilha?É bem fácil, acho que até mais fácil que o método tradicional:

- exemplo de uso da declaração with para manipular arquivos:

  ```
    with open(nome_do_seu_arquivo, modo de abertura do arquivo) as arquivo:

       #operação
  ```
- se quiser um exemplo mais prático:

  ```
    with open("trabalho.txt", "a") as arquivo:

       arquivo.write("o presente trabalho objetiva descrever...")
  ```

percebeu que eu não dei arquivo.close()?É justamente porque não precisa :)